# When is ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes not empty?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm trying out IdentityServer4 demo project and I'm adding user claims to `ProfileDataRequestContext.IssuedClaims` in `IProfileService` implementation. One thing I've noticed is that there is a `context.RequestedClaimTypes` collection, which is always empty in any resource/identity/scope configuration variations I've tried. Under what condition does this collection has data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1067

> Whenever you request a scope that has associated claims.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm hitting the same issue. How is a scope associated with claims?

Comment: @TomRegan: AFAIK IdentityResource and ApiResource has Scopes.

Answer (score 20):

If in the definition of your `ApiResources` you define `UserClaims`, these will then be populated in the `context.RequestClaimTypes`.
For example:

```
new ApiResource
{
  Name = "TestAPI",
  ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
  UserClaims = {
    JwtClaimTypes.Email,
    JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,
    JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumber,
    JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumberVerified,
    JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
    JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName,
    JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName
                    },
  Description = "Test API",
  DisplayName = "Test API",
  Enabled = true,
  Scopes = { new Scope("testApiScore) }
}
```

Then your `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestClaimTypes` will contain these request claims, for your Identity Server to fulfil how you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that it if you set `client.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true` and additional roundtrip is made to `/connect/userinfo` endpoint and the request has requested value "`sub`".